# Codeigniter active record update method not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

This is a function in my model *get_db.php* to update a table named 'person' :

```
  public function update1($data) {

    $id = $data['fname'];

     //echo $id;

      $this->db->where('fname',$id);

      $this->db->update('person',$data);

      echo "updated successfully!";

        }
```

The corresponding controller method is :

```
  public function updateValues(){

    $data['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
    $data['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');

     $this->load->model('get_db');

     $this->get_db->update1($data);

}
```

The data is successfully passing from the controller to model method(I have tested by echoing it).But this part of the model method :

`$this->db->where('fname',$id);`  is not working.

But if I pass any random string for the where clause like this :

```
$this->db->where('fname','anystring');
```

then it is working and updating my table 'person'.Basically,`$id` is not being passed correctly for some reason.Please help.

Note : `fname`,`lname` and `mobile` are the column names in my table person.

Comment: are you sure your database updating when you pass any random string?

Comment: @LokeshJain - Yes it is,I have tried it countless times.

Comment: are variable $data['fname'] and your database column fname values same? both should be same. i think here you are mistaking.

Comment: @LokeshJain- yes they are same,thats why its updating as desired when i manully pass a string in where() method for example where('fname','pradeep').It updates the table.

Comment: Where is `$id` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this
//this is controller code
public function updateValues(){

    $data['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
    $data['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $this->get_db->update1($data);
}

//model
public function update1($data) {
      $fname = $data['fname'];
      $this->db->like('fname',$fname);
      $this->db->update('person',$data);
      echo "updated successfully!";
    }
```

Comment: I tried it your way and now its updating every row regardless of what fname it has.

Answer (score 0):

`$id` should passed from controller to module.

In controller, you have to pass id to model function as condition array. You can pass record id to updateValues function as parameter. Or from POST.

```
public function updateValues($id){
    $data['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
    $data['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $this->get_db->update1($data,array("id"=>$id));
}
```

In model:

```
public function update1($data,$condition) {
    $id = $data['fname'];
     //echo $id;
      $this->db->where($condition);
      $this->db->update('person',$data);
      echo "updated successfully!";
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think best solution to update row using table id or mobile number (if unique).... because frist name or last name may be duplicate.

Comment: No there is no primary key in my table.And why is my code working if I pass value of fname by manually by a string ?

Comment: if you pass fname it update all record which find the fname. So you need id or mobile number for updation if you want update particuler record.